Creating S3 Bucket policy using Pulumi
i am trying to create a s3 bucket and a s3 policy using pulumi and typescript. But when i run the pipeline, in the test stage i am getting the below error.
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
- Expected  - 2
+ Received  + 2
@@ -8,12 +8,12 @@
          },
        },
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Resource": Array [
-         "app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket-arn",
-         "app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket-arn/*",
+         null,
+         "undefined/*",
        ],
      },
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
  }
  137 |             Statement: [
  138 |               {
> 139 |                 Effect: 'Deny',
      |                                ^
  140 |                 Principal: '*',
  141 |                 Action: 's3:*',
  142 |                 Resource: ['app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket-arn', 'app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket-arn/*'],
  at infra/resource.unit.ts:139:32
  at node_modules/@pulumi/output.ts:440:31
  at node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/output.js:21:71
  at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/output.js:17:12)
  at applyHelperAsync (node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/output.js:257:12)
  at node_modules/@pulumi/output.ts:352:13

this indicate thats null and undefine is receved for the Resource argument. Below is the code i use to create the S3 and S3 Policy.
const appS3 = new s3Bucket.S3Resource('app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket', {
bucketArgOpts: {
  args: {
    bucket: 'app-testsupun-buyapp-bucket',
    tags: {
      application: 'app',
    },
  },
},
  });

const appS3Policy = new aws.s3.BucketPolicy(
'default-testsupun-policy',
{
  bucket: appS3.bucket.bucket,
  policy: {
    Version: '2012-10-17',
    Statement: [
      {
        Effect: 'Deny',
        Principal: '*',
        Action: 's3:*',
        Resource: [
          /* pulumi.output(appS3.bucket.bucket).apply(() => `arn:aws:s3:::${bucketname}/*`), */
          appS3.bucket.arn,
          pulumi.interpolate`${appS3.bucket.arn}/*`,
        ],
        Condition: {
          Bool: {
            'aws:SecureTransport': 'false',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
{
  dependsOn: [appS3],
},
);


I think you should change dependsOn from [appS3] to [appS3.bucket].
It looks like appS3 doesn't extend from the class Resource and your dependsOn doesn't work properly. When you apply your changes in test mode Pulimi can't properly find your dependents between the resources.
